# JMeter - Access variables used in Java

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm new to JMeter. I've a Java code which I've imported as JAR file. There is a variable called `output`, in which the result is in which the output is received and is printed. I want to access that variable from Jmeter Beanshell. Can anyone help me out with that?

My Java code is as follows:

```
package co.in;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class RestClientGet_Validate {

    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://172.16.2.192:8080/pivot_service_1.0/service/validate");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            response = output;
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be informed that you can execute the request using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and obtain the output using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

---

If you're looking for a way to re-use your existing Java code in JMeter scripting test elements:

1. You need to change return type of your function to [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), to wit replace

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```

   with

   ```
   public static String main()
   ```

   2. You need to add [return statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) at the end of your function like:

      return output;
   3. Once done place the .jar to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and restart JMeter to pick it up
   4. If everything goes well you should be able to access the value in Beanshell like:

      String output = co.in.RestClientGet_Validate.main();

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting so consider migrating from Beanshell ASAP.